# Is it possible to use std::make_unique in a class constructor and `this` pointer?

Tags: c++, constructor, unique-ptr

I am trying to use unique_ptr instead of raw pointers for components that are assigned to an actor class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Component;

class Actor
{
public:
        void AddComponent(std::unique_ptr<Component> component)
        {
                std::cout << "Add component\n";
                mComponents.push_back(std::move(component));
        }

        void RemoveComponent(Component* component)
        {
                std::cout << "Removing Component...\n";
                auto iter = std::find_if(mComponents.begin(), mComponents.end(),[&](const auto& e){ return e.get() == component;});
                if(iter != mComponents.end())
                {
                        mComponents.erase(iter);
                        std::cout << "Removed from vector \n";
                }
        }

        void ListComponents()
        {
                for(const auto& element : mComponents)
                {
                    std::cout << "Component:" << element.get() << "\n";
                }
        }
private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component> > mComponents;
};

class Component
{
public:
        Component(Actor* actor) : mOwner(actor) {actor->AddComponent(std::make_unique<Component>(*this));}
        virtual ~Component() { std::cout << this << ":Destroyed \n"; }
private:
        Actor* mOwner = nullptr;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        Actor Actor1;
        auto c1 = Component(&Actor1);
        auto c2 = Component(&Actor1);
        Actor1.ListComponents();
}
```

Is there a way to assign the `this` pointer to a unique_ptr, or am I right that I need to use a factory function of some kind?

Thanks!

EDIT:  Corrected Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Component;

class Actor
{
public:
        void AddComponent(std::unique_ptr<Component> component)
        {
                std::cout << "Add component\n";
                mComponents.push_back(std::move(component));
        }

        void RemoveComponent(Component* component)
        {
                std::cout << "Removing Component...\n";
                auto iter = std::find_if(mComponents.begin(), mComponents.end(),[&](const auto& e){ return e.get() == component;});
                if(iter != mComponents.end())
                {
                        mComponents.erase(iter);
                        std::cout << "Removed from vector \n";
                }
        }

        void ListComponents()
        {
                for(const auto& element : mComponents)
                {
                    std::cout << "Component:" << element.get() << "\n";
                }
        }
private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component> > mComponents;
};

class Component
{
public:
        Component(Actor* actor) : mOwner(actor) {actor->AddComponent(std::unique_ptr<Component>(this));}
        virtual ~Component() { std::cout << this << ":Destroyed \n"; }
private:
        Actor* mOwner = nullptr;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        Actor Actor1;
        auto c1 = new Component(&Actor1);
        auto c2 = new Component(&Actor1);
        Actor1.ListComponents();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three issues here.

1. There are various syntax errors (missing declaration of `Component` before the definition of `Actor`, typos, ... I'll ignore them now they are mentionned.
2. The if you have any pointer, you can build a `unique_ptr` from it which will handle the lifetime of the object. That's not made with `make_unique` but with the constructor:

   ```
   owner->AddComponent(std::unique_ptr<Component>(this));
   ```
3. You can do that but the `unique_pointer` will manage the lifetime of the Component. So that means that nothing else should and you have to avoid that, especially temporaries and stack allocated one. So you'll have to replace:

   ```
   c1 = Component(&Actor1);
   c2 = Component(&Actor1);
   ```

   by something like:

   ```
   new Component(&Actor1);
   new Component(&Actor1);
   ```

   There are various way to enforce that so that mistakes are detected at compilation, but I'll not go into them.

Comment: Thanks - I can't believe I didn't see that.  I also should have used all my test code, not just pieces I thought were important.  I updated with all old and updated to reflect your response.  I am just debating whether it is better to have the `Actor` object own components and have them clean up on destruction, or keep the fine grained ability to remove them, but then have to have use `deletes`.